# My Game makes a run time exception

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I looked for the exception but the solution said that i should delete a function from a class but this class is not in my code

i searched alote before i made this topic

these is the log cat of the exception:

```
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x5dbbab68, tid 1007
01-01 00:10:34.100 1622-1622/com.jdev.c60 E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-01 00:10:35.370 1622-1622/com.jdev.c60 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                             Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit
                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:117)
                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34)
                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:61)
                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load gdx from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.jdev.c60-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.jdev.c60-1]: findLibrary returned null
                                                                at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
                                                                at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:113)
                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxNativesLoader.load(GdxNativesLoader.java:34) 
                                                                at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.<clinit>(AndroidApplication.java:61) 
                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319) 
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-01 00:10:36.230 646-1011/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-01 00:00:00.000 0-0/? E/Internal: device 'emulator-5554' not found
```

Goode bye :)

Comment: wild guess - you need libgdx.so in your apk

Comment: And where can i put this file in my project ? Core/gamebase/android ? And in whch folder @SteelBytes